# Docker container unable to write to removable drive

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, docker, external-hdd

I currently am running Ubuntu Jammy and have a docker container that needs to write to two external drives that were automatically mounted to /media/MYUSER/MYDRIVE while both are mounted correctly and the docker container says it has read/write access to the drive and I am able to write to the drive with my user, when the docker container tries to write to the drive it throws a permissions error and is only able to read. Chmod (777) seems to not have any effect on the permissions and when I checked my fdisk file the drives are not even listed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.